# Encapsulation with multiple classes C#

Tags: c#, encapsulation

So my question is over basic encapsulation. I know I am setting up my getters and setters right (I actually have a question later about this) but I have multiple classes. I have another class and I understand that I am making pieces of my code view-able to my outside class by making certain things public. So I think I set up my first code file right. (Some background, I have a class that is connecting to a database and then another that is encapsulating all the data. The first code section posted is the encapsulating part, I then post my three methods I was messing up on.)

I feel okay with the getting and setting, I feel a little unsure of my constructor. I feel like I put my variables in the parameter list so that I put values in them from my outside class? Right? or should I be putting public forms of my private variables in my other code file and then passing those into my constructor in that same file?

/ this my first code file

```
using System;

public class clsEncapsulate
  {
    private int mID;
    private string mName;
    private string mClassification;
    private DateTime mConvocationDate;
    private string mLocation;

public int ID
{
    get
    {
        return mID;
    }
    set
    {
        mID = value;
    }
}

public string Name
{
    get 
    {
        return mName;
    }
    set 
    {
        mName = value;
    }
}

public string Classification
{
    get
    {
        return mName;
    }
    set 
    {
        mName = value;        
    }
}

private DateTime ConvocationDate
{
    get
    {
        return mConvocationDate;
    }
    set
    {
        mConvocationDate = value;
    }
}

private string Location
{
    get
    {
        return mLocation;
    }
    set
    {
        mLocation = value;
    }
}

public clsEncapsulate(int id, string name, string classification, DateTime convocationDate, string location)
{
    bool running = false; 

    while(running == false)
    {

    ID = mID;
    Name = mName;
    Classification = mClassification;
    ConvocationDate = mConvocationDate;
    Location = mLocation;

    running = true;

    }
}
```

}

In my second code file I am just going to put the methods that I am having trouble with.

```
private void refreshbox()
{
    string formattedConvocation;
    string formattedDateTime;
    string formattedConvocationName;

    lstConvocations.Items.Clear();
    foreach (clsEncapsulate currentConvocation in mConvocationAL)
    {
        formattedConvocationName = currentConvocation.Name;
        formattedConvocationName = truncateString(formattedConvocationName, 30);

        formattedConvocation = formattedConvocationName.PadRight(33);
        formattedConvocation += currentConvocation.Classification.PadRight(17);

        formattedDateTime = currentConvocation.ConvocationDate.ToShortDateString().PadRight(10)
            + currentConvocation.ConvocationDate.ToShortTimeString().PadLeft(8);
        formattedConvocation += formattedDateTime;

        lstConvocations.Items.Add(formattedConvocation);
    }
}
```

Alright, so in order for my second code file to manipulate the variables in the first code file, I need to expose them to this method. I didn't know if I should be putting my public variables in the constructor, or if I should be declaring them somewhere in my first code file. I was very unsure of how to expose these variables to this method. I've fiddle around with it but my book doesn't address this situation exactly and I was having trouble figuring it out.

If someone does answer this question please break down why you're going to put what you're going to put! I want to understand why, say, I put my public variables in one place, and not another. Or why I declare an object of my encapsulate class in one place and not another. I was trying to declare an encapsulate object in my method so it would give this method access to the variables, but it wasn't working! Please tell me what I was doing wrong or if you want me to post more of my code.

Below are the two other methods I was messing up on.

/ second method from my second code file I was messing up on:

```
private void displayProperties(int index)
{
    if (index == -1)
    {
        return;
    }

    clsEncapsulate selectedValue = (clsEncapsulate)mConvocationAL[index];


    txtConvocationName.Text = selectedValue.Name;
    txtConvocationClassification.Text = selectedValue.Classification;
    txtConvocationDate.Text = selectedValue.ConvocationDate.ToShortDateString();
    txtConvocationTime.Text = selectedValue.ConvocationDate.ToShortTimeString();
    txtConvocationLocation.Text = selectedValue.Location;
    txtID.Text = selectedValue.ID.ToString();
}
```

/ last method I was messing up on:

```
  private void readConvocations(string filterConstraint, string sortField, string     sortOrder)
{
        OleDbConnection connection = null;
    OleDbDataReader reader = null; 

    try
    {
        connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = mConnectionString;

        connection.Open();

        string statement = "SELECT ID, Name, Classification, Location, Date FROM Convocations ";
        if(filterConstraint != "")
           {
                statement += "WHERE Name LIKE " + toSQL(filterConstraint, true) + " "; 
           }
            string statement2 = statement;
        statement = string.Concat(new string[]
        {
            statement2, "ORDER BY ", sortField, " ", sortOrder

        });

        OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(statement, connection);
        reader = oleDbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        mConvocationAL.Clear();

        while(reader.Read())
        {

            clsEncapsulteconvocation = new clsEncapsulate();
            convocation.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
            convocation.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
            convocation.Classification = (string)reader["Classification"];
            convocation.Location = (string)reader["Location"];
            convocation.ConvocationDate = (DateTime)reader["Date"];

            mConvocationAL.Add(convocation);

        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Close();
        }

        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Tell me if you need me to elaborate more to help you understand my situation. I am new at learning vocabulary and want to understand this! Thank you for helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is one public object and a bunch of private methods so its difficult to get the overall picture of how your code it working together but there are a few principles you can apply to make your code better structured, now and in the future.

Have a read about SOLID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). The S and the D would apply well to your example.

Also you mentioned construtors and private properties. Try looking into Imutable types. That means once the object is created you cannot change it. For your clsEncapsulate class that would mean making your fields read only and remove the public setters.

Good luck.

Comment: I think I am getting a better go at this, thank you! If I have other problems I'll just post below.